# Pig into Cassandra - pass list objects using python UDF and CqlStorage

Tags: cassandra, user-defined-functions, etl, apache-pig

I am working on a dataflow including some aggregating steps in Pig and storing steps into Cassandra. I have been able to pass relatively simple data types such as integer, long or dates but can't find how to pass some sort of list, set or tuple from Pig to Cassandra using CqlStorage.

I use Pig 0.9.2, so I can't use the FLATTEN methods.

### Question

**How do I fill a Cassandra table carrying complex data types such as sets or lists from Pig 0.9.2?**

### Overview of my specific application:

- I created the corresponding Cassandra table respecting the description:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE mycassandracf (
  my_id int,
  date timestamp,
  my_count bigint,
  grouped_ids list<bigint>,
  PRIMARY KEY (my_id, date));
  ```
- and a STORE instruction carrying prepared statement:

  ```
  STORE CassandraAggregate
  INTO 'cql://test/mycassandracf?output_query=UPDATE+test.mycassandracf+set+my_count+%3D+%3F%2C+grouped_ids+%3D+%3F'
  USING CqlStorage;
  ```
- From a 'GROUP BY' relation, I 'generate' a relation in a cql-friendly format (e.g. in tuples), that I want to store into Cassandra.

  ```
  CassandraAggregate = FOREACH GroupedRelation
      GENERATE TOTUPLE(TOTUPLE('my_id', $0.my_id),
      TOTUPLE('date', ISOToUnix($0.createdAt))),
      TOTUPLE(COUNT($1), $1.grouped_id);

  DUMP CassandraAggregate;

  (((my_id,30021),(date,1357084800000)),(2,{(60128490006325819),(62726281032786005)}))
  (((my_id,30165),(date,1357084800000)),(1,{(60128411174143024)}))
  (((my_id,30376),(date,1357084800000)),(4,{(60128411146211875),(63645100121476995),(60128411146211875),(63645100121476995)}))
  ```

Unsurprisingly, using the STORE instruction on this relation raises the exception:

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pig.data.DefaultDataBag cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray

I thus add a UDF written in python to apply some flattening on the grouped_id bag:

```
@outputSchema("flat_bag:bag{}")
def flattenBag(bag):
    return tuple([long(item) for tup in bag for item in tup])
```

I use tuple because using python sets as well as python lists ends up in getting casting errors.

Adding it to my pipeline, I have:

```
CassandraAggregate = FOREACH GroupedRelation
    GENERATE TOTUPLE(TOTUPLE('my_id', $0.my_id),
    TOTUPLE('date', ISOToUnix($0.createdAt))),
    TOTUPLE(COUNT($1), py_f.flattenBag($1.grouped_id));

DUMP CassandraAggregate;

(((my_id,30021),(date,1357084800000)),(2,(60128490006325819,62726281032786005)))
(((my_id,31120),(date,1357084800000)),(1,(60128411174143024)))
(((my_id,31120),(date,1357084800000)),(1,(60128411146211875,63645100121476995,6012841114621187563645100121476995)))
```

Using the STORE instruction on this last relation raises the exception with error stack:

```
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
at     org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:465)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.processOnePackageOutput(PigGenericMapReduce.java:428)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:408)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:262)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:176)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:652)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:420)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:266)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:260)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlRecordWriter$RangeClient.run(CqlRecordWriter.java:248)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:129)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_execute_prepared_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1724)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.execute_prepared_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1709)
at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlRecordWriter$RangeClient.run(CqlRecordWriter.java:232)
```

I tested the exact same workflow with simple data types and is working perfectly. What I am really looking for is the way to fill a cassandra table with complex types such as sets or lists from Pig.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigation, I found the solution here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5867

Basically, CqlStorage supports complex types. For that, the type should represented by a tuple in the tuples, carrying as first element the very data type as a string. For list, this is how one does this:

```
# python
@outputSchema("flat_bag:bag{}")
def flattenBag(bag):
    return ('list',) + tuple([long(item) for tup in bag for item in tup])
```

Thus, in grunt:

```
# pig
CassandraAggregate = FOREACH GroupedRelation
    GENERATE TOTUPLE(TOTUPLE('my_id', $0.my_id),
    TOTUPLE('date', ISOToUnix($0.createdAt))),
    TOTUPLE(COUNT($1), py_f.flattenBag($1.grouped_id));

DUMP CassandraAggregate;

(((my_id,30021),(date,1357084800000)),(2,(list, 60128490006325819,62726281032786005)))
(((my_id,31120),(date,1357084800000)),(1,(list, 60128411174143024)))
(((my_id,31120),(date,1357084800000)),(1,(list, 60128411146211875,63645100121476995,6012841114621187563645100121476995)))
```

This is then stored into cassandra using classic encoded prepared statement.

Hope this will of some help.

Comment: I am using DSE3.2.4 where in it is Pig0.9.2, I don't have ISOToUnix() in pig. so what would be the best way to load date into cassandra? My date format is 'yyyy/MM/dd'

Comment: @sudheer ISOToUnix is actually an UDF from piggybank, not a builtin method. Here is what you need to add to access the method:

`REGISTER /path-to-your-jar/piggybank.jar;                                       
DEFINE ISOToUnix org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.convert.ISOToUnix();`

Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: Sorry I can't Find Piggybank.jar, Thats what I was trying to convey in last msg. I am Using DSE3.2.4, Generally I find it in contrib folder in Cloudera, is it that I missed something in my installation or Datastax doesn't provide piggybank?

Comment: I don't know where DSE puts its pig lib folder, but if you can locate it, look for the jar in: **/path-to-dse-pig-libs/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar**

I use a manual install of hadoop/pig and can find my pig libs in: /usr/local/lib/pig-*